# How to make my NMT not translate (or remove) special characters?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, nmt

I am using a pre-trained version of MarianMT.

It happens that I would like the model not to translate (or eliminate certain characters) special, since they protect me from certain information that should not be translated by the model. For example my character can be

.

I've seen them use arguments like add_special_tokens. But it hasn't worked for me, the model keeps trying to translate that token or there are cases where it deletes it.

I tried using add_special_tokens in the model